# Does zwebcam (from zbar-tools) work with Thinkpad X300 built-in camera?

Tags: linux, webcam, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use the [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) webcam barcode scanner on a Lenovo Thinkpad X300 running Debian Linux.  I get a nice greyscale image and the barcode shows clearly, but nothing gets recognized.  I'm wondering if others can report

- Does `zbarcam` work on the X300?
- Does `zbarcam` work on any laptop with a tiny, fixed-focus camera?

Capture resolution is 320x240.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with the ZBar people, it's pretty clear that the built-in camera on the X300 does not offer enough resolution.